# Does copying files from EXT4 filesystem to NTFS lose permissions?

Tags: permissions, backup, ntfs, ext4, cp

I recently attempted to back up my /home/user directory while removing **ecryptfs** from my system. I didn't have enough space on my Ubuntu EXT4 SSD so, not thinking, I used

```
sudo cp -rp /home/user /media/user/HDD
```

to copy it to my NTFS HDD before removing it. Obviously when I copied it back the permissions had been overwritten from what it used to be. My question: is there any way to recover these permissions etc...(i.e. does the `-p` flag preserve them in some other way on a NTFS system), or were they lost as soon as I copied them over?

Additionally, is it just the UNIX permissions that NTFS systems don't handle well, or is there anything else I should be worried about?

Comment: NTFS is not a posix compatible file system, and cannot store the permissions as it has different permission bits (/sys /mod /ro /inv as I recall).  It's not a`cp` issue, the NTFS cannot store this information  The easiest way I've found around it is saving this information to a file (even a long complete `ls -lR` type listing; then a script reads it & writes the permissions back) but not using NTFS is far easier.

Comment: Since NTFS will not keep permissions or ownership, you can look into using `setfacl` and create a restore file that you can use after copying back from your backup off NTFS.

Comment: Or just use an archiver like tar which will copy and restore the permissions.